# How do I edit a Date to display in a different format?

Tags: java, android, date

I am storing datetime as text in the format **dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss** in SQLite database. I want to convert it to a date object in the same format. I'm only able to convert it to the format **Mon Jun 16 01:35:38 GMT+05:30**. How can I have it as a `Date` object of the required format? Here `TSArray[]` contains the dates in string format:

```
int dateArraySize=TSArray.length;
Date dateArray[]=new Date[TSArray.length];
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

for (int i=0;i<TSArray.length;i++) { 
    try { 
        //converting String date to Date 
        Date result=df.parse(TSArray[i]);
        dateArray[i]= result;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Just a reminder: `H` = hour in day `(0-23)`, `h` = hour in am/pm `(1-12)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` objects in Java simply represent an instant in time (specifically, the number of milliseconds before or after the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)) - they don't store any information about how they should be displayed, nor should they. Formatting a date is purely for display purposes, and is the concern of the `DateFormat` hierarchy of classes and shouldn't be done until display time (unless you have a compelling reason to do it earlier than that, but I can't think of a *good* one).

There's arguably nothing to stop you sending a `DateFormat` object alongside your `Date`, but you should never need to if you properly internationalise your code in the first place.

One reason that you *shouldn't* do this is down to the difference in regional date formats. If you presented me with the date `03/07/2014`, I'd see that as the 3<sup>rd</sup> of July 2014, because here in the UK we format our dates as `DD/MM/YYYY`. Present the same date to someone in the USA and they'll see it as March the 7<sup>th</sup> 2014, because US dates are typically `MM/DD/YYYY`.

The database and the server don't need to know any locale information about the client, they should simply serve the requests for data where appropriate and let the client (which *does* know the locale information) format that data appropriately.

**TL;DR**:

You can't, because Java `Date` objects don't store display formatting rules.

---

As you're using AChartEngine you should be able to achieve what you're after by using a `TimeChart` and passing in the date format mask via a call to the chart's `setDateFormat(String)` method.

Comment: But i need to convert it into a proper format so that i can use it in my graph . Im using achartengine and it requires me to use date object and the present format of my date is not suitable for the graph. what do i do?

Comment: So use a `TimeChart` and set the display format mask using `setDateFormat(String)`.

Comment: Iam using a TimeChart. I realise that date object is in the right format, but still my graph does not get displayed. and x axis does not take my date values. It has the values 1-1-1970 05:30:00

Answer (score -1):

Database return value in java.sql.date n java default you are using java.util.date. Java.util.date convert into java.sql.Date like below given..

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      
Java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```